# How can I send mail using python when there is two factor authentication(eg: outlook + duo mobile for otp)

Tags: python-3.x, smtp, office365

I have tried sending mail using smtp using the guide given here : https://realpython.com/python-send-email/ but the program was stuck without giving any output or error. After a bit of debugging I found that it was stuck at the login phase and I figured that it could be due to the two factor authentication hence I would like to know what can be done in this situation when the sender and receiver both are using Outlook.

I tried searching on how we can send mail using python when there is two factor authentication but could not find any concrete answer.

The goal is to send a mail(using python) from outlook account to another outlook account when there is two factor authentication enabled for log in.